# Organize a version control system for a legacy system

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch, alm

We are investigate how to using modern code version systems for a legacy systems.
However, there are some difficulties that we do not really know how to solve. How do you think we should going to organize this?

1. Some parts of the code we have responsibility for, and some parts the customer are responsibility for.

   The code that is in our development system is the master, and all changes are made there and then sent out to the customer. So far is it like a common project. But for some directories with a few hundred files, the client is responsible for the code. Customer can change these files as they want, and do not have inform us. When we do an update for them, we need to get a copy of these files and merge our changes before we give the new version to the customer.
2. We have released 4 base versions of the system over the 25 years the system have lived. Our six customers, however, use different versions of the system, which means that we have to consider it. In addition, each customer has their own requirements, and we have made major adjustments for each customer.
3. We have several parallel projects related to the same files. Today we have major problems that the various projects interfere with each other, so we will benefit greatly from having changes in different branches. But how do we organize this?
   Some projects affect only one customer, other projects involving several customers. And some projects may be introduced into a new future base version.

So my question is how to organize this in our new version system.

Comment: IMHO this is not a version control issue. This is a "bad legacy system" issue. You can't have users screwing with source code, not even for customization. You need to isolate the code that the users change by putting it into a separate binary, separate project, or something like that. Any code that the user modifies cannot practically be modified by you, ever.

Comment: You are absolutely right. There will be a lot of problems when the customer has the opportunity to modernize some of the code. A few days ago, I got a problem when I had a final test in Germany for a project. I discovered that I had the wrong version of the code. My code had simply been overwritten with the code from the customer when a colleague imported the latest code changes from the customer. And since we do not yet have any version control, I had to search in backups and try to locate the correct version.

Comment: But the customers has worked like this for 25 years, and it hard to change the way to work. So we simply have to adapt to how we work, no matter what we think about it, and try to make the best of it.

Comment: Sorry, but you're mistaken. You don't have to continue shooting yourself in the foot. You can do better. You didn't define an extensibility strategy 25 years ago, but you can do so now. Take all the customer code, and your "original" code, fix up the namespaces (invest in ReSharper), then start refactoring. Remove all the duplication, and what will be left is the differences among the customers. These differences will be the places where the customers needed to customize. Use modern techniques to produce equivalent code (base classes with virtual overrides, for instance).

Comment: Also, try to take the opportunity to introduce unit tests, both of the original code, and of the customer code. When you're finished with this cleanup, you'll have new code to give back to each customer, which will be the code that they customized. Also give them a copy of the common code. You will also have identified a set of extensibility points that customers can use. Document those points, _and don't let the customers change anything else_.

Comment: The code is written in Fortran 77, and there are no more modern compiler system. Moreover the customer is very restrictives to make some changes. We talk about nuclear power plants, and if there is something that works, they wanted absolutely not change anything, no matter how much we want.
You are absolutely right in everything you write. I am new to the project, and it's frustrating to work after so old principles. That's why I try to make the best of the situation according to the circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, when you said "legacy", I had no idea! I believe that the technical term for your situation is "SOL".

Comment: I don't know what "SOL" is.
But if we ignore the reason why it is as it is. How can I make the most of this from the worthless requirements we have on us?

Comment: The last two letters of "OL" stand for "Out of Luck". I don't see a source control solution to this problem.